# Search and output with Python

Tags: python, io

Help guys!!!

List of 150 text files,

```
One text file with query texts: (  
    SRR1005851  
    SRR1299210  
    SRR1021605  
    SRR1299782  
    SRR1299369  
    SRR1006158  
    ...etc).
```

I want to search for each of this query texts from the list of 150 text files.
if for example `SRR1005851` is found in at least 120 of the files, `SRR1005851` will be appended in an output file.
the search will iterate all search query text and through all 150 files.

Summary: I am looking for which query text is found in at least 90% of the 150 files.

Comment: So, what have you tried? Show us your code, show us where you're stuck, and we might be able to help.

Comment: What have you done so far? What is the specific issue that you are facing while actually CODING for this?

Comment: I have written the following code. I have an idea of what is required but I am not sure how to make it work. please help me guys
count=0
with open("expressed.txt", "w")as result:
    with open("C:/Users/ifeanyi/Desktop/modify/Bmori_id.txt", "r")as query_file:
        for matches in query_file:
            for name in glob.glob("*.txt"):
                with open(name, "r") as compared:
                     for lines in compared:
                        if matches in lines:
                            count=+1
                            result.append(count)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think I fully understand your question. Posting your code and an example file would have been very helpful.

This code will count all entries in all files, then it will identify unique entries per file. After that, it will count each entry's occurrence in each file. Then, it will select only entries that appeared at least in 90% of all files.

Also, this code could have been shorter, but for readability's sake, I created many variables, with long, meaningful names.

Please read the comments ;)

```python
import os
from collections import Counter
from sys import argv

# adjust your cut point
PERCENT_CUT = 0.9

# here we are going to save each file's entries, so we can sum them later
files_dict = {}

# total files seems to be the number you'll need to check against count
total_files  = 0;

# raw total entries, even duplicates
total_entries = 0;

unique_entries = 0;

# first argument is script name, so have the second one be the folder to search
search_dir = argv[1]

# list everything under search dir - ideally only your input files
# CHECK HOW TO READ ONLY SPECIFIC FILE types if you have something inside the same folder
files_list = os.listdir(search_dir)

total_files = len(files_list)

print('Files READ:')

# iterate over each file found at given folder
for file_name in files_list:
    print("    "+file_name)

    file_object = open(search_dir+file_name, 'r')

    # returns a list of entries with 'newline' stripped
    file_entries = map(lambda it: it.strip("\r\n"), file_object.readlines())

    # gotta count'em all
    total_entries += len(file_entries)

    # set doesn't allow duplicate entries
    entries_set = set(file_entries)

    #creates a dict from the set, set each key's value to 1.
    file_entries_dict = dict.fromkeys(entries_set, 1)

    # entries dict is now used differenty, each key will hold a COUNTER
    files_dict[file_name] = Counter(file_entries_dict)

    file_object.close();


print("\n\nALL ENTRIES COUNT: "+str(total_entries))

# now we create a dict that will hold each unique key's count so we can sum all dicts read from files
entries_dict = Counter({})

for file_dict_key, file_dict_value in files_dict.items():
    print(str(file_dict_key)+" - "+str(file_dict_value))
    entries_dict += file_dict_value

print("\nUNIQUE ENTRIES COUNT: "+str(len(entries_dict.keys())))

# print(entries_dict)

# 90% from your question
cut_line = total_files * PERCENT_CUT
print("\nNeeds at least "+str(int(cut_line))+" entries to be listed below")
#output dict is the final dict, where we put entries that were present in > 90%  of the files.
output_dict = {}
# this is PYTHON 3 - CHECK YOUR VERSION as older versions might use iteritems() instead of items() in the line belows
for entry, count in entries_dict.items():
    if count > cut_line:
        output_dict[entry] = count;

print(output_dict)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what i wanted. I just make a few adjustment on the files and it worked like magic. thanks so much bro. thanks stackoverflow...

Comment: Awesome bro, please mark answer and upvote if you will.